# Even after setting proper z-index it's not working on ipad safari.

Tags: ios, css, safari, mobile-safari

I have really bad situation. I have my custom div which I m showing under page. The only issue I have at moment that it's not working on iPad.  The overlay covers the popup even after I have proper z-index to both element.

This issue only facing with iPad safari. On other browser it's working fine. I found one solution where I need to shift my popup next to or near by overlay div which is not possible for me due to binding context of knockout.js

The issue snap [image]

here as you can see the attached image the opened calender is behind the overlay gray div.
[image]

Below is the html structure where the higlited is the calender container & at last overlay div.

Let me know if some can suggest me some good idea to deal with this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like if your fixed element is inside an other fixed element that has lower z-index than overlay it will stay behind it even if the element itself has a higher z-index. So you have to find that higher fixed element and change it's z-index to something higher.

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 4;
}
.lower {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2
}
.popup {
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="lower">
  <div class="popup"></div>
</div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: The only issue I have that I can not place this element next to each other, I mean at same level. I have different hierarchy of html div & that causing issue just for ipad safari,

Comment: It seems like an element in your hirarchie has also position fixed plus a lower z-index than overlay.

Answer (score 0):

It's also happen for me in Safari, simply I solve it by remove `overflow:hidden` from parent div.